# How exatly a multi core processor performs better than a single core processor?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I was reading about concurrency in java and I came across many interesting things.
Please help me understand the working of multi core processors.

from official docs

> A computer system normally has many active processes and threads. This
>   is true even in systems that only have a single execution core, and
>   thus only have one thread actually executing at any given moment.
>   Processing time for a single core is shared among processes and
>   threads through an OS feature called time slicing.
>
> It's becoming more and more common for computer systems to have
>   multiple processors or processors with multiple execution cores. This
>   greatly enhances a system's capacity for concurrent execution of
>   processes and threads — but concurrency is possible even on simple
>   systems, without multiple processors or execution cores.

So first of all, as per my understanding, a process has its own memory space
and in systems with single core the memory space is shared between processes using time slicing.

So

1. Is it that in multiple core processors time slicing is not needed ?
2. Do different processes run on different cores in a multiple core system ?
3. a little abstract : how exactly a multiple core system is faster ?

Comment: I would say they execute things in parallel mode and thats the reason why they are faster

Comment: I feel a need to make a note: having multiple cores does not guarantee that things perform better; depending on the nature of the code it might perform worse. Sometimes a whole lot worse.

Answer (score 3):

1) time slicing still happens on multicore systems. Say you have 20 processes running (plus the OS itself) on a quadcore - the OS still has to schedule 21 processes to run on only 4 cores.

2) a single-threaded process runs on only one single core at a time. But that doesn't mean it'll run on the *same* core until it exits. The OS might give him a time slice to run on Core 1 now, pause it, and give it another time slice on Core 2 later. As far as I know, the OS will avoid moving processes between cores, but this might still happen

3) Well, you have multiple processors working at a time. Much like 4 builders would build a house faster than 1 builder alone. But that doesn't mean they'll build it 4 times as fast - each builder will have the overhead of cooperating and communicating with his teammates, so 4 builders might build the house 3, maybe 3.5 times as fast. Much like 4 cores vs 1 core.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a Web service like Gmail, where you can send a request by Ajax for for example search emails that start with the letter "L", which is Asynchronous call, which  means that during the time that you send that request, one of your cores, is handling that communication but the other can continue the navigation in the web page. So basically what allow you is work in paralel doing two CPU process at the same time and don't have to share the CPU time, which is faster indeed.
One of the reasons of the creation of multicore processor was basically Asynchronous in the program languages.